# Javascript Promise.all not running then

Tags: javascript, promise

I've got a series of promises.

I never get the console log "Processed folders" printed out. Execution seems to stop once it hits the first `await Promise.all` call.

Not entirely sure where I've missed up?

```js
const subfolders = [];

const exportFolder = () => {
    // Other stuff happening here

    const subfolder = {};
    subfolder.items = [];
    subfolder.items.push({ name: 'item 2.1' });
    
    const folder = {};
    folder.items = [];
    folder.items.push({ name: 'item 1' });
    folder.items.push({ name: 'item 2', isFolder: true, items: subfolder.items });
    
    console.log('Folder:', folder);

    console.log('Started');
    exportFolderToCsv(folder).then(response => console.log('Finished', response));
};

const exportFolderToCsv = async folder => {
    console.log('Processing folders');

    let promises = [];

    for (const folderItem of folder.items) {
        if (folderItem.isFolder && folderItem.items.length > 0) {
            subfolders.push(folderItem);
            return;
        }

        promises.push(processFolderItem(folderItem));
    }

    await Promise.all(promises).then(response => console.log('Processed folders:', response));

    if (subfolders.length > 0) {
      console.log('Processing subfolders');

      promises = [];

      for (const folderItem of subfolders.items) {
        promises.push(processFolderItem(folderItem));
      }

      await Promise.all(promises).then(response => console.log('Processed subfolders:', response));
    }

    console.log('Finished');
};

const processFolderItem = folderItem => new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('Processing folder item');
    
    // To stuff here with folderItem, get Doc Chars, process row and resolve

    getCharacters(folderItem)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Processed folder item characters list:', response);
            createCSVRow(folderItem, response)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('Processed CSV row:', response);
                    resolve(response);
                })
        });
});

const getCharacters = folderItem => new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('Processing folder item characters list');
    
    // To stuff here with folderItem and then resolve
    const characters = 'Foobar characters';

    resolve(characters);
});

const createCSVRow = (folderItem, characters) => new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('Processing CSV row');

    // To stuff here with folderItem and characters and then resolve
    const csvRow = 'Foobar row';

    resolve(csvRow);
});

exportFolder();
```

Comment: Your code just defines a couple of functions but never actually calls anything. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: @str I've added a snippet that you can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is returned before any Promise call is executed, it should be `continue`. So please resolve it first.

```js
const exportFolderToCsv = async (folder) => {
  // ...

  for (const folderItem of folder.items) {
    if (folderItem.isFolder && folderItem.items.length > 0) {
      subfolders.push(folderItem)
      return // here lies the problem, it should be `continue` instead
    }

    promises.push(processFolderItem(folderItem))
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Promise.all` method, will catch errors if at least one Promise in chain throws an error or reject it.

It seems that one of your promises got an exception.

You can debug it simply adding the `catch` like so:

`Promise.all(PromiseList).then(()=>console.log("all works done") ).catch(errors=>console.log("something wrong",errors))`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using await there is no point in chaining.

```
let response = await Promise.all(promises);
console.log('Processed subfolders', response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your promises will encounter errors, and you need to consider the failed situations.
At the same time, `Promise.all` will stop if either one promise failed, so maybe your `Promise.all` failed.

```
try {
  Promise.all(promises).then(response => console.log('Processed subfolders', response));
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
// or to check your promise result
const folderResult = await Promise.all(promises);
```

to check the exact result